# DD command broke partition table Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, dd

I have two exact same model and capacity hard drives with the first one having Ubuntu Server 16.04 (`/dev/sda`) on it and the second (`/dev/sdb`) having formerly been part of RAID configuration on different system. I wanted to clone the `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb` for which I used command `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` from a Ubuntu LiveCD but after the command has ended the output of fdisk -l gave:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcf7ffe95

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 1953523711 1952522242  931G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 1953523711 1952522240  931G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 930.1 GiB, 998663782400 bytes, 1950515200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I assume the `dd` command somehow destroyed the partition table on `/dev/sdb`  but what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Because you did not tell `dd` to keep the mbr? That command you do in 1 go ... in my memory that always is THREE commands. edit: like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252536/10017

Comment: Am I right to assume that the section labeled 'Cloning an entire hard disk' in this [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning#Using_dd) offers a one liner to clone both data and MBR of the hard disk due to the `bs=64K`  part of the command?

Comment: quickest fix is to use testdisk https://cstan.io/?p=8878&lang=en "Analyse and Quick Search" allows you to rewrite the 1st 512kb.

Comment: Already tried the testdisk but its 'quick search'  needs hours to finish searching for partitions if not more. Edit: actually, probably a day or more